# sql server decimal data type issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

*Decimal data type  in table Length = 9,Precision = 10,Scale = 2,*
*actual value in @Bvisits = 8.00*

```
declare @Bvisits decimal,@ActualVisit decimal,@Ptax decimal = 1.995;
select @Bvisits = BalanceVisit from PakacgeTb where PackageID = 25306;

set @ActualVisit = @Bvisits - @Ptax;

select @ActualVisit as VIP
```

*result is 6.*

*But as i use it in real stored procedure it updates result as 4.67 instead of 6 why is the issue occurring even if i use 1.9 instead of 1.995 still same issue occurs.*

Comment: The code you posted has *no* precision or scale defined, which means they have default values. Whatever you read will be converted to the defatul precision and scale. Anyway, post a *reproducible example*. That means, you have to post the table schema as well and show the actual values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i found out the issue was in my stored procedure rather than data type decimal

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
declare @Bvisits decimal(10,3),@ActualVisit decimal(10,3),@Ptax decimal(10,3) = 1.995;
select @Bvisits = BalanceVisit from PakacgeTb where PackageID = 25306;

set @ActualVisit = @Bvisits - @Ptax;

select @ActualVisit as VIP
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: created a new table and tested on it worked perfectly on decimal but on this table won't work .. ?

Comment: what is datatype of "BalanceVisit" in PakacgeTb table

Comment: Even i try to use 8.00 - 2.0 still shows value 4.67

Comment: Decimal data type in table Length = 9,Precision = 10,Scale = 2 this is the data type , i used same data type on other table and showed the result i wanted but in this table won't show\

Comment: can u shared the table script ?

Comment: @RinkiPanwar, Execute this Query in your SSMS: `select 8.00 - 2.0`, what is the result ?

Comment: 6.00 is the result @ahmed

Comment: BalanceVisit decimal no 9 10    2     no (n/a) (n/a) NULL ||| this is the script @udhaya

Comment: i think problem is in your stored procedure,table script not a problem

Comment: @RinkiPanwar, if the result is `6.00` where is the issue ??

Comment: @RinkiPanwar, Try Debug your procedure carefully.

Comment: yes you were right ahmed i found the issue it was updating another line which caused this issue thanks again.